# R Shiny: using a reactive output in UI

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm building a shiny app that will sum population counts by user-defined cut points. could be any number of cut points from 0-100.

my thought is to have the user define the number of age categories they want and then have them enter in the ranges. To do this I installed the package `shinyMatrix`.

Ideally, I'd like the number of rows in the matrix to be equal to the number of cuts the user defined but this requires a reactive value in the UI function.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("breaks", "Enter number of age groups", 0, min= 1, max= 100),
    matrixInput("grid", value= matrix(NA,6,2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("lower", "upper"))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE),
                  cols = list(names = TRUE)),
    actionButton("calc", "Calculate")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4("Population Sum by group"),
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
  )
))
```

so where the 6 is in the `matrixInput` it should be something like `output$breaks`

[image: app view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `updateMatrixInput` on the server side to update the "grid", setting the number of rows equal to `input$breaks`

```
  observeEvent(input$breaks, {
    updateMatrixInput(session,inputId = "grid",
                      value = matrix(NA,input$breaks,2,dimnames =list(NULL,c("lower","upper"))))
  })
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: Insightful answer @langtang ! How does it work when there are multiple filters applied to the dataset? I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435043/use-shiny-reactive-from-server-as-ui-input) as well.