# Use Shiny Reactive from server as UI Input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am struggling to use the result of a reactive function as input for the UI.
Currently, I am mostly using renderUI which decreased performance as the app got more complex.

Using

```
DetailsList(items = filtered_Accounts(), columns = columns.top.accounts, checkboxVisibility = 2)
```

in the UI function did not work because it could not access the reactive?

Below is a shortened example with only two filters:

UI:

```
# Column Definitions for Table -----------
columns.top.accounts <- tibble(
  fieldName = c("text", "occupation", "Gender", "age.floor", "Nationality","n_friends_formatted", "n_followers_formatted"),
  name = c("Name", "Occupation", "Gender", "Age" , "Nationality" ,"# of Friends", "# of Followers")
)

# UI - Filters -----------
filters.descriptive <- Stack(
  tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
  Label("Filter by Twitter user", className = "my_class"),
  NormalPeoplePicker.shinyInput(
    "selectedAccounts",
    class = "my_class",
    options = df.Account.Info
    )
  ),
  Slider.shinyInput("slider",
                    value = 0, min = 0, max = 600000, step = 1000,
                    label = "Minimum number of friends",
                    valueFormat = JS("function(x) { return x}"),
                    snapToStep = TRUE
  )
)

# UI-Function --------------
ui <- function(input, output, session) {
  filters.descriptive,
  uiOutput("table.top.accounts")
}
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # ---- Reactive --------------
  filtered_Accounts <- reactive({
    req(input$slider)
    selectedAccounts <- (
      if (length(input$selectedAccounts) > 0) input$selectedAccounts
      else df.Account.Info$key
    )
    
    filtered_Accounts <- df.Account.Info %>%
      filter(
        key %in% selectedAccounts,
        n_friends >= input$slider
      )
  }) %>% debounce(750)

  # Outputs Descriptive ------------------

  output$table.top.accounts <- renderUI({
    items_list <- if(nrow(filtered_Accounts()) > 0){
      DetailsList(items = filtered_Accounts(), columns = columns.top.accounts, checkboxVisibility = 2)
    } else {
      p("No matching transactions.")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I believe I have to use [observe ({})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712265/how-to-use-the-result-of-using-reactive-function-as-input-in-ui-r-shiny) here but I was not able to apply it to my case successfully.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the packages you use, and  make the code reproducible? The section labelled UI filters has an extra parentheses, etc.